# How to remove an element after a 3 delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-lists

```
$('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').animate({opacity: 1}, 1250).remove(); //results in instand remove
$('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').delay(3000).remove(); //instant remove
$('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').remove().delay(3000); //that didnt work either
```

How can I remove the object after 3 seconds instead of being instantly removed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').remove();
},3000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `setTimeOut($('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').remove, 3000)` work as well? That's a serious question, I don't know (it works in Python, but Python is not JS...).

Comment: @delnan, it should work but the example Manny gave is easier to understand and follow.

Comment: @delnan, that should be okay because first parameter accepts a function or a string, however you cannot add any parameters in your case so I used an example that is more flexible, because when the time comes that you need parameters in your function, better to wrap it in function() {} declaration

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do the it `.delay` way, you'll need to incorporate a [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$("#gallerie ul li:eq(1)").delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MT4Yd/

Answer (score 2):

The `delay` method is used for animations, so only animation methods that are chained after it are delayed. The `delay` method places a delay on the animation queue, it doesn't delay the execution of the code.

To remove elements after an animation, you can use it's callback method. Example:

```
$('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').fadeOut(3000, function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[The manual page](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) says (quite clearly, actually):

"Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the `.delay()` method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue."

`remove()` won't use the effects queue.

You can use jQuery's `fadeOut()`, `hide()` ... or as a complete equivalent to your original attempt, [Javascript's basic `setTimeout` function.](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: No problems. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').remove();
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$('#gallerie ul li:eq(1)').animate({opacity: 1}, 1250,function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```